# Как сделать галерею с загрузкой изображения при клике на миниатюру?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Нужно сделать галерею, чтобы изображение загружалось при клике на миниатюру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как делаются такие галереи? Возможно есть готовые плагины?

Comment: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider

Comment: Нужно без слайдера. Нажали на миниатюру, фотография подгрузилась и поменялась.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов Вы скорее всего имеете в виду "нужно без анимации". Посмотрите в настроки плагина. Там есть опция скорости анимации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего реализации такого слайдера есть замечательный плагин - [Fotorama](http://fotorama.io). Он позволяет делать и миниатюры, и листание по свайпу на мобильных устройствах, и индикатор загрузки есть:

```html
<!-- 1. Link to jQuery (1.8 or later), -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- 33 KB -->

<!-- fotorama.css & fotorama.js. -->
<link  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- 3 KB -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script> <!-- 16 KB -->

<!-- 2. Add images to <div class="fotorama"></div>. -->
<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
</div>
```

При желании анимацию, если она вам не требуется в данном случае, можно отключить, или изменить:

```html
<!-- 1. Link to jQuery (1.8 or later), -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- 33 KB -->

<!-- fotorama.css & fotorama.js. -->
<link  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- 3 KB -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script> <!-- 16 KB -->

<!-- 2. Add images to <div class="fotorama"></div>. -->
<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-transition="slide" data-clicktransition="crossfade">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
//создаем обработчик события на клике по миниатюре:
$('#gallery img').click(function(){
   //получаем адрес картинки из дата-тега:
   var adress=$(this).data('src')
   //устанавливаем полученное значение в src основной картинки
   $('#big img').attr('src',adress)
})
```

```css
#gallery img{
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big">
<img src="https://placehold.it/300.png/09f/fff">
</div>
<div id="gallery">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100.png/09f/fff" data-src="https://placehold.it/300.png/09f/fff">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100.png/f90/fff" data-src="https://placehold.it/300.png/f90/fff">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100.png/f09/fff" data-src="https://placehold.it/300.png/f09/fff">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100.png/0f9/fff" data-src="https://placehold.it/300.png/0f9/fff">
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант ничем не отличается от моего. Только в моем еще показывается индикатор загрузки картинки.